# Build failed on netlify

Tags: reactjs

Below is the error i get when i try to host my react app on netlify. I dont understand what the error is, can someone please help me solve the issue?

```
10:43:35 PM:   Error message
10:43:35 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
10:43:35 PM: ​
10:43:35 PM:   Error location
10:43:35 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
10:43:35 PM:   npm run build
10:43:35 PM: ​
10:43:35 PM:   Resolved config
10:43:35 PM:   build:
10:43:35 PM:     command: npm run build
10:43:35 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
10:43:35 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
10:43:35 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
10:43:35 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
10:43:36 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:43:36 PM: Finished processing build request in 27.355s
10:43:36 PM: Failed during stage "building site": Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
```

Comment: Please check this link; it might be helpful in resolving the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789192/build-fail-while-deploying-react-app-to-netlify